# SQL equivalent of Pandas pandas.util.hash_pandas_object

Tags: sql, pandas, dataframe, md5, amazon-athena

I need to write the logic ti generate unique value for each row,i know i can use MD5 hash, but i have a limitation that in past we have used pandas dataframe way of generating unique value by using above mentioned method, but now we are using sql way, so we want to use generate the same kind/data tyle of value for each row we did using pandas method.

Can anyone help here? MD5 hash generates in alphanumeric, but above pandas method generates unique values in integer.

Comment: Do you need to have the generated ID consistent across the queries or it is fine to be random? Can you provide some sample data and desired output (also the same for python would be nice)?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Athena is based on PrestoDB so I think you can generate MD5 hashes for your data like below :

1. **Generate the MD5 Hash**:

   ```sql
   SELECT
       to_utf8(column_name) AS utf8_encoded_column,
       md5(to_utf8(column_name)) AS md5_hash
   FROM your_table;
   ```

   I used the  `to_utf8(column_name)` to convert the column data to a format that can be hashed. Replace `column_name` with the column name you want to hash.
2. **Convert Part of the Hash to Integer**:

   You can then take a substring of the hash and convert it to an integer. The MD5 hash in Athena is represented as a `varbinary` type, so you might need to convert it to hexadecimal string representation first.

   ```sql
   SELECT
       CAST(from_base64(SUBSTRING(CAST(md5(to_utf8(column_name)) AS VARCHAR), 1, 8)) AS BIGINT) AS unique_integer
   FROM your_table;
   ```